# Angular2 using webpack yarn

Tags: angular, webpack, tslint, yarnpkg

For our project we are using Angular2 with webpack and yarn. when we try to run the app using `webpack --config webpack/webpack.dev.js` we are getting an error saying:

```
ERROR in ./src/main/webapp/app/app.main.ts
Module build failed: Error
at new FatalError (D:\workspace\deploy\webpackTest\marketplace\node_modules\
tslint\lib\error.js:33:23)
at Function.findConfiguration (D:\workspace\deploy\webpackTest\marketplace\n
ode_modules\tslint\lib\configuration.js:97:15)
at resolveOptions (D:\workspace\deploy\webpackTest\marketplace\node_modules\
tslint-loader\index.js:26:64)
at Object.module.exports (D:\workspace\deploy\webpackTest\marketplace\node_m
odules\tslint-loader\index.js:110:17)

ERROR in ./src/main/webapp/app/vendor.ts
Module build failed: Error
at new FatalError (D:\workspace\deploy\webpackTest\marketplace\node_modules\
tslint\lib\error.js:33:23)
at Function.findConfiguration (D:\workspace\deploy\webpackTest\marketplace\n
ode_modules\tslint\lib\configuration.js:97:15)
at resolveOptions (D:\workspace\deploy\webpackTest\marketplace\node_modules\
tslint-loader\index.js:26:64)
at Object.module.exports (D:\workspace\deploy\webpackTest\marketplace\node_m
odules\tslint-loader\index.js:110:17)

ERROR in ./src/main/webapp/app/polyfills.ts
Module build failed: Error
at new FatalError (D:\workspace\deploy\webpackTest\marketplace\node_modules\
tslint\lib\error.js:33:23)
at Function.findConfiguration (D:\workspace\deploy\webpackTest\marketplace\n
ode_modules\tslint\lib\configuration.js:97:15)
at resolveOptions (D:\workspace\deploy\webpackTest\marketplace\node_modules\
tslint-loader\index.js:26:64)
at Object.module.exports (D:\workspace\deploy\webpackTest\marketplace\node_m
odules\tslint-loader\index.js:110:17)
```

The `tslint.json` file is:

```
{ 
    "rules": { 
        "no-unused-expression": true, 
        "no-duplicate-variable": true,
        "no-duplicate-key": true, 
        "no-unused-variable": true, 
        "curly": true, 
        "class-name": true, 
        "semicolon": [false],
        "semicolon": ["always"], 
        "triple-equals": true
    }
}
```

I tried with different versions of tslint, but it's not working.

Comment: Can you please add the webpack and tslint files?

Comment: Note that the GitHub flavour of code markdown (triple backtick) does not work here.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run `webpack --config webpack/webpack.dev.js --display-error-details`.